# SwiftUI bindings not work with children hierarchy

Tags: swift, swiftui

I need to refresh ContentView after timeout on one of the child of a child. For some reason this code does not work:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var returnToHome: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        TabView([
            TabBarItem(view: HomeView(),
                       image: Image("home_icon"),
                       title: "home"),
            TabBarItem(view: AskView(returnToHome: self.$returnToHome),
                       image: Image("ask_icon"),
                       title: "ask us"),
            TabBarItem(view: JobsView(),
                       image: Image("jobs_icon"),
                       title: "jobs"),
            TabBarItem(view: MeetingView(),
                       image: Image("meeting_icon"),
                       title: "meeting"),
            TabBarItem(view: MoreView(),
                       image: Image("more_icon"),
                       title: "more")
        ])
    }
}

struct AskView: View {
    @Binding var returnToHome: Bool

    var body: some View {
        AskDone(returnToHome: self.$returnToHome)
    }
}

struct AskDone: View {
    @Binding var returnToHome: Bool

    var body: some View {
            Text("done!")
        }
        .onAppear {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
                self.returnToHome = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code inside DispatchQueue is performed but it does not affect ContentView @State.
I've also tried to pass Binding but without success.
What can be the problem?

Comment: I don't see any condition on `returnToHome`, what would you expect it actives?

Comment: @Asperi, I expect it to renew ContentView body, which will re-create TabView with initial Home screen

Comment: There is no reason for this, because nothing depends on `returnToHome`.

Comment: @Asperi in my understanding "body" should be updated anytime when any State of of the View is changed. Am I wrong?

Comment: Theoretically yes, but it is declared officially that SwiftUI rendering engine optimized to do not any unneeded re-build/re-draw if nothing changed, and this is very good, actually. In your case nothing changed, so nothing updated.

Comment: @Asperi, you were right, after adding variable to body it is now updated! Add this as answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in my understanding "body" should be updated anytime when any State of of the View is changed. Am I wrong?

Theoretically yes, but it is declared officially that SwiftUI rendering engine optimized to do not any unneeded re-build/re-draw if nothing changed in view hierarchy, and this is very good, actually. In your case nothing changed, so nothing updated. You have to add some dependency in `body` on `returnToHome`.